# Proving that $\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)= 90^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

The question starts with $y=\arccos(x)$ and asks to express $\arcsin(x)$ in the form of $y$.

I got $x=\cos(y)$ and then used $\cos(y)=\sin(y+90)$, so $x=\sin(y+90^{\circ})$ and then $\arcsin(x)=y+90^{\circ}$.

From there I then said that if $\arcsin(x)=y+90^{\circ}$ and $\arccos(x)=y$, $\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)= 2y+90^{\circ}$, but I know it should just be $90^{\circ}$.

The solution uses $\cos(y)=\sin(90^{\circ}-y)$ but since $\sin(90^{\circ}-y)=\sin(y+90^{\circ})$. I don't understand why my answer comes out differently.

Comment: $y=\arccos x$ implies $\cos y=x$ but $a=\cos b$ does not imply $b=\arccos a$.

Comment: why not? x and y are just variables

Comment: For example $0 =\cos (\frac  {\pi} 2+1000\pi)$. But $\frac  {\pi} 2+1000\pi \neq \arccos 0$. See the definitioin of $\arccos$ to see why $\arccos $ cannot be large number. In fact $arccos 0=\pi/2$ not $\pi /2 +1000\pi$.

Comment: So how would I use this in my answer? How would I know to use sin(90-y) rather than sin(y+90)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176711/is-it-generally-true-that-arcsin-theta-arccos-theta-frac-pi2

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this class of problems without running into issues in boundary of the domains is geometrically. Since you have $y = \arccos(x) \implies x = \cos y$ think about a right triangle $\Delta ABC$ with $\angle B = 90^\circ$ and $y = \angle A$.

You are free to scale this any way you like, so let's pick the hypotenuse $AC=1$ and then your constraint says $AB=x$.

Now you need to find $\arcsin(x)$, in other words, the angle for which $x$ would be the sine. Looking at our $\Delta ABC$ it is easy to see that $\sin C = x$ and the measure of $C$ must be
$$
\angle C
 = 180^\circ - \angle A - \angle B
 = 180^\circ - y - 90^\circ
 = 90-y.
$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $y=\arccos x\iff \cos y=x \textbf{ and } y\in[0,\pi]$.

On the other hand, $y=\arcsin x\iff \sin y=x \textbf{ and } y\in\bigl[-\frac \pi 2,\frac\pi 2\bigr]$.
 Taking into account the intervals condition, you get
$$\arcsin x=\frac\pi 2-y.$$